# Execute Linux file written in Python using Java program

Tags: java, python, ycsb

I'm using ***YCSB(Yahoo! Cloud Serving Benchmark)*** for performance measurement of 2 node **Cassandra(2.0.2)** cluster deployed on **CentOS**. For loading data using YCSB I executed the following --

```
bin/ycsb load cassandra -P workloads/cassandraLoadA -s files/load.dat
```

This line uses property file **cassandraLoadA** and and stores the YCSB generated  in **load.dat** . Here **ycsb** file is written in Python. Now I want to execute the above from a Java program. I tried with **ProcessBuilder** and **Runtime** object but failed.
 Using ProcessBuilder Object-

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/DIRECTORY_HERE/bin/ycsb","load","cassandra","-P", "workloads/cassandraLoadA","-s","files/load.dat");
Map<String, String> environ = builder.environment();
final Process process = builder.start();
```

Using Runtime Object -

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd /DIRECTORY_HERE/bin/ycsb load cassandra -P workloads/cassandraLoadA -s files/load.dat");
p.waitFor();
```

Q1 : Am I doing anything wrong here ?
Q2 : How can it be accomplised ?

Best Regards-
Avijoy

Comment: Question may be downvoted but tried ways are mentioned so at least one can give correct ways before down voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try composing the whole command as a String and then pass it to the ProcessBuilder

Comment: A comment will be helpful to undersatnd the downvote :(

Comment: Add redirectErrorStream(true) and update your questing with the error message

Answer (score -1):

Add '&&' between cd and execution command,
Try this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd /DIRECTORY_HERE/bin && ycsb load cassandra -P workloads/cassandraLoadA -s files/load.dat");
```

p.waitFor();

Hope helped you!